# Xcode 13: Multiple command produce the same framework error

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcframework

since an update to Xcode 13, I have had trouble with building my project. My app target needs to embed two frameworks. Before the new Xcode, there was no problem with embedding A.framework and B.framework simultaneously. Framework B is using framework A inside, so it is added in framework B as not embed dependency.

App:

- embed A.framework
- embed B.framework

Framework B:

- not embed A.framework

When I'm building, I'm getting multiple errors:

```
Multiple commands produce A.framework:
1) Command ProcessXCFramework
2) Target A has link command with output
```

I really don't understand why there is mentioned .xcframework which this target isn't using anywhere.

Could someone know how to fix my issue?

Comment: Any updates on this issue? I have a similiar one.